# What is wrong with this PDO statement? Cannot use object of type PDOStatement as array

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

***I want to fetch every result from table 'Themes'.***

```
function display_all_themes()
{
    global $pdo;    
    $select = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM themes");
    $select->execute();

    while ($row = $select->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        echo $select['theme_name'].'<br />';
    }
}
```

Getting this error:

Fatal error: Cannot use object of type PDOStatement as array in C:\xampp\htdocs\driptone\inc\functions.inc.php on line 137

Line 137:

```
    echo $select['theme_name'].'<br />';
```

**What is the problem?
*Thanks.***

Comment: PHP errors are pretty explicit. When it says " Cannot use object of type PDOStatement as array " it means that at some place where you are supposed to use an array - in the echo in your case - you're using something else than array, which means that select is not an array, which means that you're supposed to use something else than $select. And also you have $row unused, this should get your attention.

Answer (score 3):

You're using `$select` instead of `$row` inside loop.

```
while ($row = $select->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))    {
    echo $row['theme_name'].'<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use **$row**, except $select

```
echo $row['theme_name'].'<br />';
```

Answer (score 2):

You assigned it to `$row` but you're calling `$select`.

Should be:

```
while ($row = $select->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))    
{
    echo $row['theme_name'].'<br />';
}
```